# Print a PDF file from Excel with "client" (from win32com)

Tags: python, automation, client, openpyxl, win32com

I had this problem, this is a super simple way to create your PDF documents with Excel, using the win32com.client library:

```
def xlpdf(self):
    app = client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
    app.Interactive = False
    app.Visible = False

    # **self.style_sheet** is the Excel workbook previously loaded with openpyxl.loadworkbook
    wb = app.Workbooks.open(self.style_sheet)

    # **self.style_options.currentText()** is a combobox that already exists, that allows me to choose which page of the book I want to convert to PDF
    wb.worksheets(self.style_options.currentText()).Activate()

    output = r'Some_dir_path_name.pdf'

    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output)
    wb.Close()

    os.system('taskkill /f /im excel.exe')
```

I hope it is useful! It serves for many things in a company and saves a lot of time, at least my application is to create PDF's massively.

Traté con otras opciones que son para un objeto así:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.loadworbook('Excel_dirname.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can see the complete project here: https://github.com/dgabrielsl/xl-pdf_drawer

Comment: But what is your question? And please use English for all text in the question.